# How to properly configure Virtual Box network settings?

Tags: networking, macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

I need to set up vms in Virtual box in a following way:

- All virtual machines (Ubuntu) must communicate with host (macOS).
- All virtual machines must communicate with each other.
- All virtual machines must communicate with Internet.

How do I achieve that? I have tried adding multiple adapters with different combinations (NAT, bridged, internal), but I can't get it right.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A bridged adapter acts as a bridge between your host (MacOS) and your Guest VMs, meaning your host will be sharing its network adapter with your VM.

From the VirtualBox manual Chapter 6 (6.5) of Virtual networking, section Bridged networking :

> With bridged networking, VirtualBox uses a device driver on your host system that filters data from your physical network adapter. This driver is therefore called a "net filter" driver. This allows VirtualBox to intercept data from the physical network and inject data into it, effectively creating a new network interface in software. When a guest is using such a new software interface, it looks to the host system as though the guest were physically connected to the interface using a network cable: the host can send data to the guest through that interface and receive data from it. This means that you can set up routing or bridging between the guest and the rest of your network.

To achieve what you need, **assign each VM the bridged adapter** that is bridged to your current network adapter on your host. this way, all VMs will be able to communicate with your host and outside of your local network.

Follow this link for more info:
[https://geek-university.com/oracle-virtualbox/configure-bridged-networks/#:~:text=With%20bridged%20networking%2C%20VirtualBox%20uses,creates%20a%20software%20network%20interface.](https://geek-university.com/oracle-virtualbox/configure-bridged-networks/#:%7E:text=With%20bridged%20networking%2C%20VirtualBox%20uses,creates%20a%20software%20network%20interface.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces of different VMs need to be configured the same way for any inter-VM connectivity. If bridged adapters don't work, another option is creating [NAT network](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat_service). The VMs will be able to communicate with each other and the host both directions. They can also communicate with external devices, but not the other way round. Incoming traffic needs to be configured with port forwarding.